Go to definition but for Makefile variables?
I am wondering if there is a tool which creates an index of makefiles used in project, so I can navigate through variables with go-to-definition like using any C/C++ IDE.
Now I am supporting a big legacy project for an embedded system which (obviously) has a Makefile and dozens of *.mk files which actually do the job. All targets, prerequisites, commands are defined implicitly depending on target/compiler/used modules ...
Here is an example of some linker options depending on what kind of target we are building for and what firmware we want to get (ordinary one, or for updating via bootloader i.e. different start address in flash)
ifeq($(TARGET),STM32)
ifeq ($(FRMW_FOR_BOOTLOADER),Y)
LDOPT += -e address_for_bootloader
LDMEMORY = $(platform_dir)/memory_for_bootloader.ld
else
LDOPT += -e \_reset_address2
....

I don't know the which TARGET is set currently, or if FRMW_FOR_BOOTLOADER is set to Y or which value address_for_bootloader has. And I have to search that kind of variables manually in different *.mk files all the time which is very time consuming.  Sure I can modify makefiles and print everything I want in console, but is it the only option?

I am not aware of any LSP server for makefiles.  Something like this will be difficult because the values of makefile variables are often context-dependent; that is the value used when a variable is expanded in one place in the makefile may not be the same as the value used when it's expanded in a different place.  In your example, the value of TARGET when that ifeq statement is expanded might be completely different than the value of TARGET after all the makefiles have been parsed and the value was possibly reset.

Another option is to invoke make -p which will print the complete, final database of variables (and rules).  You can check the output for the values of variables you are interested in.  Note, though, as in my previous comment that this is the final value of the variable; it might not be the right value for that variable at a specific location in the makefile, if the variable was reset later.

Unfortunately, printing variables in the makefile is about the only real way to see what the heck is going on in makefiles, and even that isn't always useful.

You might want to study make's documentation for details.
The option -n does not actually run any recipe, it just prints them.
The option -d prints an overwhelming amount of debugging information.
